# How to change Integration Runtime for the pipeline activities in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I would like to change the default integration runtime for my pipeline activities, but I was not able to do that. Do you know how can I do it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure integration runtime can access data stores and services from public networks only. You can always see one Azure integration runtime called `AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime`. This is the default integration runtime, and the region is set to auto-resolve.

Refer MS doc for more details: [Integration runtime in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime)

For **every linked service** that you create, you can **choose** the Integration runtime you want. You cannot set this at a pipeline scope.

[image]

Comment: Hi KarthikBhyresh-MT,

Thanks for explaining this is very helpful. But my main goal was to get one dedicated IP for my specific pipeline activity.  Do you know how I can achieve this?

Comment: If am not wrong, I think you are looking for this - You can use [self hosted integration runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory#considerations-for-using-a-self-hosted-ir) with [private endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-private-link). Again, when you say "specific pipeline activity" - if its like only the `CopyActivity` in the pipeline has to have it, then you can set your self hosted IR in the linked service for the source and sink in the copy activity.

Comment: yes, thanks for the answer,that was very helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

I found one more place to change the IR for Pipeline activity:

[image]